# Reorder dictionaries within a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list containing dictionaries that looks like this:

```
[{'isin': 'IE000000001', 'MP': 'B', 'market_share': 30}, {'isin': 'IE000000002', 'MP': 'C', 'market_share': 50}, {'isin': 'IE000000003', 'MP': 'D', 'market_share': 70}]
```

I would like to reorder the dictionaries in my list based on their 'market share' so that I would end up with something like that

```
[{'isin': 'IE000000003', 'MP': 'D', 'market_share': 70}, {'isin': 'IE000000002', 'MP': 'C', 'market_share': 50},{'isin': 'IE000000001', 'MP': 'B', 'market_share': 30}]
```

Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Did you try anything? What happened? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need pandas for this.

```
# sort the list by market_share
my_data.sort(key=lambda x:x['market_share'], reverse=True)
my_data
[{'isin': 'IE000000003', 'MP': 'D', 'market_share': 70},
 {'isin': 'IE000000002', 'MP': 'C', 'market_share': 50},
 {'isin': 'IE000000001', 'MP': 'B', 'market_share': 30}]
```

Answer (score 1):

@not_a_robot answered it already, just to give you an alternative answer, you can use the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function like so :

```py
new_list = sorted(your_list, key=lambda d: d['market_share'], reverse=True)
```

Comment: thank you, i have to start using this lambda functions :)

Comment: Watch out for the `reverse`d order

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sorted()` function and specify things like the `key` argument (what value to sort by) and the `reverse` argument (whether to sort descending or ascending). In this case, you want to sort by `dictionary['market_share']` so `key=lambda dictionary:dictionary['market_share']`. You also want to sort by decreasing market share, so `reverse=True`. All of this together gives

```py
data = [{'isin': 'IE000000001', 'MP': 'B', 'market_share': 30}, {'isin': 'IE000000002', 'MP': 'C', 'market_share': 50}, {'isin': 'IE000000003', 'MP': 'D', 'market_share': 70}]
data = sorted(data, key=lambda dictionary: dictionary['market_share'], reverse=True)
```